# Wrong quantity is displaying in Backend because of overwriting

Tags: multi-vendor, qty-increment

we have **Marketplace Multi vendor**/seller site, means sellers can sell the products through our site.

we are using an extension to implement this.

Before using an extension, we can see correct quantity under **Catalog > Manage Products.**

In extension , there is a **bug** so that,

under Catalog > Manage Products we can see "Quantity" for each product, This **quantity is a combination of all sellers**.

example : Products "A" have 2 sellers.

**seller A** is base seller with **10** quantity and **seller B** assigned the same product with **5** quantity.

So its displaying **15** under ***Manage Products > quantity***.

Extension is **over riding** the default Quantity Feature.

I want to remove this over riding.

I guess this is code for the overriding :

```
app/code/local/webkul/Mpassignproduct/Model/Mpassignproduct.php

<?php

class Webkul_Mpassignproduct_Model_Mpassignproduct extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct');
    }

    public function editproduct($data) {
        $sellerId=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $products=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',array('eq'=>$sellerId))
                            ->addFieldToFilter('mpassignproduct_id',array('eq'=>$data['pro_id']));
        if(count($products)) {
            foreach($products as $product) {
                $isApproved=$product->getFlag();
                $preQty=$product->getQty();
                $product->setQty($data['qty']);
                $product->setPrice($data['price']);
                $product->setProductCondition($data['product_condition']);
                $product->setProductDescription($data['product_description']);
                $saved=$product->save();
                $lastId=$saved->getId();
            }
        }
        if($lastId)  {
            if($isApproved == 1) {
                $_product=Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($data['product_id']);
                $qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
                $qtyStock = ($qtyStock - $preQty) + $data['qty'];
                $this->_saveStock($data['product_id'],$qtyStock,1); 
            }
            $this->uploadImages($lastId);
        }

        return $lastId;
    }

    public function assineproduct($data) {
        $data['seller_id'] = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $product = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct');
        $product->setData($data);
        $status = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/product_approval') ? 2 : 1;

        $product->setFlag($status);
        $product->setCreatedAt(Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $saved=$product->save();
        $lastId=$saved->getId();

        if($lastId) {
            if($status == 1) {
                $_product=Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($data['product_id']);
                $qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
                $qtyStock = $qtyStock + $data['qty'];
                $this->_saveStock($data['product_id'],$qtyStock,1); 
            }
            $this->uploadImages($lastId);
        }
        return $lastId;
    }

    public function uploadImages($lastId) {
        $target =Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/mpassignproduct/'.$lastId.'/';
        if(isset($_FILES) && count($_FILES) > 0) {
            if(!is_dir(Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/mpassignproduct/')) {
                mkdir(Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/mpassignproduct/', 0755);
            }
            if(!is_dir(Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/mpassignproduct/'.$lastId.'/')) {
                mkdir(Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/mpassignproduct/'.$lastId.'/', 0755);
            }
            foreach($_FILES as $image ) {
                if($image['tmp_name'] != '') {
                    $splitname = explode('.', $image['name']);
                    $splitname[0] = str_replace('-', '', $splitname[0]);
                    $image_name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $splitname[0]);
                    $target1 = $target.$image_name.".".$splitname[1];
                    move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'],$target1);
                }
            }               
        }
    }

    public function _saveStock($lastId,$stock,$isstock) {
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
        $stockItem->loadByProduct($lastId);
        if(!$stockItem->getId()){$stockItem->setProductId($lastId)->setStockId(1);}
        $stockItem->setProductId($lastId)->setStockId(1);
        $savedStock = $stockItem->save();
        $stockItem->load($savedStock->getId())->setQty($stock)->save();
        if($stock) {
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', $isstock); 
        }
        $savedStock = $stockItem->save();
    }

    public function getAssignProDetails($productid) {
        $collection=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                            ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0))
                            ->addFieldToFilter('flag',array('eq'=>'1'))
                            ->setOrder("price","ASC");
        $data=array();                          
        $totalAssignQty=0;
        $priceFrom=0;               
        foreach($collection as $item) {
            $price=$item->getPrice();
            break;
        }           
        foreach($collection as $item) {
            $totalAssignQty = $totalAssignQty + $item->getQty();
        }   
        $productModel = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productid);
        if($productModel->getPrice() < $price)
            $priceFrom=$productModel->getPrice();
        else
            $priceFrom=$price;
        $totalProductQty = $productModel->getStockItem()->getQty();
        $data['sellerqty'] = $totalProductQty - $totalAssignQty;
        $data['assignqty'] = $totalAssignQty;
        $data['pricefrom'] = $priceFrom;
        $data['assignCount'] = count($collection);
        return $data;
    }   

    public function getSellerList($productid) {
        $customerId=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid));
        $i=0;
        foreach($collection as $item) {
            $sql2=Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($item['seller_id']);
            $item['logo']=$sql2['logopic'];
            $item['sellername']=$sql2['firstname']." ".$sql2['lastname'];
            $sql[$i]=$item;
            $i++;
        }
        return $sql;
    }

     public function detailsale($mageproid, $userid) {
        $data = array();
        $sum=0;
        $arr=array();
        $quantity = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',array('eq'=>$mageproid))
                            ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',array('eq'=>$userid));
        $data['quantitysoldconfirmed']=0;
        $data['quantitysoldpending']=0;
        foreach($quantity as $rec) {
            $status=$rec->getCpprostatus();
            $qty=$rec->getMagequantity();
            if($status==1) {
                    $data['quantitysoldconfirmed']=$data['quantitysoldconfirmed']+$qty;
            } else if($status==0) {
                    $data['quantitysoldpending']=$data['quantitysoldpending']+$qty;
            }
        }
        $amountearned = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',array('eq'=>$mageproid))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',array('eq'=>$userid));
        foreach($amountearned as $rec) {
            $sum=$sum+$rec->getactualparterprocost();
            $arr[]=$rec->getClearedAt();
        }
        $data['amountearned']=$sum;
        $data['clearedat']=$arr;
        $quantitysold = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',$mageproid)
                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',$userid);
        $data['quantitysold']=0;
        $data['quantitysold']=0;
        foreach($quantitysold as $rec) {
            $qty = $rec->getMagequantity(); 
            $data['quantitysold']=$data['quantitysold']+$qty;

        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function detsalebyid($productId, $userid) {
        $data = array();
        if($productId > 0) {
           $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
           $collection->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',array('eq'=>$productId));
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',array('eq'=>$userid));
            $i=0;
            foreach ($collection as $record) {
                $data[$i]=array(
                            'magequantity'=>$record->getmagequantity(),
                            'actualparterprocost'=>$record->getactualparterprocost()
                        );
                $i++;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is not the bug in this extension. this extension work like number of total number of quantity by all seller of that product. so in admin this is showing correct quantity for selling.

let me take your example.

seller A is **base seller** with **10** quantity and seller B assigned the same product with **5** quantity.

so the total number of quantity for the purchased is **15** quantity.

So its displaying `15` under Manage `Products > quantity`. **that are correct.**

if you change the main quantity to **`10` of seller a** you will `lose` your **5 quantity of seller b**.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
  class Webkul_Mpassignproduct_Model_Mpassignproduct extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct');
    }

    public function editproduct($data)
    {
        $sellerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();

        $products = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',array('eq'=>$sellerId))
                            ->addFieldToFilter('mpassignproduct_id',array('eq'=>$data['pro_id']));
        if(count($products)) {
            foreach($products as $product) {
                $isApproved = $product->getFlag();
                $preQty = $product->getQty();
                $product->setQty($data['qty']+$product->getQty());
                $product->setPrice($data['price']);
                $product->setProductCondition($data['product_condition']);
                $product->setProductDescription($data['product_description']);
                $saved=$product->save();
                $lastId=$saved->getId();
            }
        }
        if($lastId)  {
            if($isApproved == 1) {
                $_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($data['product_id']);
                $qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
                $qtyStock = ($qtyStock - $preQty) + $data['qty'];
                $this->_saveStock($data['product_id'],$qtyStock,1); 
            }
            $this->uploadImages($lastId);
        }

        return $lastId;
    }
}
```

Comment: i checked it, but same result....

Comment: $isApproved=$product->getFlag(); can you exp?

Comment: or which function call to update qty?

Comment: i guess this is the function : :_saveStock($lastId,$stock,$isstock)"

Comment: sorry , i have no idea about this : "$isApproved=$product->getFlag();" as it is extension.